# Dúvida sobre método em Java

Tags: java

Alguém saberia me dizer como eu passo o valor de um parâmetro pelo método "invoke" em Java?

Eu tenho um método que recebe como parâmetro uma String (Esse é o método que quero invocar).

Porém eu estou utilizando um método genérico que recebe como parâmetro uma classe, e retorna uma String.

Resumidamente, estou fazendo isso:

```
Method mt = classe.getMethod("getSQL");
    Object invoke = mt.invoke(classe, filtro);
```

O parâmetro "classe" é a classe de onde eu quero buscar o método, e o "filtro" é o parâmetro que gostaria de mandar para o método que quero invocar.

Entretanto estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.com.viasoft.orion.model.evolucaovendas.EvolucaoVendas.getSQL()
```

Se alguém conseguir ajudar, fico grato.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection

Comment: Show de bola o material, ajudou aqui. Vlw!!

Comment: Verificou nome do método na classe?

Comment: Sim, o problema era justante o parâmetro, pois antes quando não tinha parâmetro, eu conseguia sem maiores problemas. Mas agora deu certo, vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a indicação de um material sobre o Java Reflection, encaminhado via comentário, descobri o problema que estava ocorrendo.

Nessa linha: `Method mt = classe.getMethod("getSQL");`, era necessário colocar o tipo de parâmetro que o método espera, ficando então assim:`Method mt = classe.getMethod("getSQL, String.class");`